# Installing ODI gives "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass"

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to install the Oracle Fusion MiddleWare ODI 12.2.1.4.0 and getting the below error running the jar file. I'm not able to figure out how to resolve this error.

```
C:\Users\test\Downloads\V983389-01>java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_odi.jar
Launcher log file is C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-06-09_10-50-42AM\launcher2022-06-09_10-50-42AM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Done
Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 2592    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.   Actual 4294967296    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB    Passed
Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 64    Passed (64-bit not required)
Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 267890 MB    Passed
Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-06-09_10-50-42AM
Log: C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-06-09_10-50-42AM\install2022-06-09_10-50-42AM.log
Jun 09, 2022 10:51:07 AM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector <clinit>
SEVERE: null
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:197)
        ... 
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:345)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:482)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:445)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:356)
        at oracle.as.install.engine.config.xml.EngineConfigParser.getEngineConfig(EngineConfigParser.java:65)
        ... 
        ... 30 more

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass" is null
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:311)
        ... 
        at oracle.sysman.oio.oioc.OiocOneClickInstaller.main(OiocOneClickInstaller.java:717)
Unable to copy the logs to the permanent location: The permanent log directory is unknown (null)..

The log(s) can be found here: C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-06-09_10-50-42AM.
C:\Users\test\Downloads\V983389-01>java -version
java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I am getting the same error and cant seem to get passed it

Comment: I used JDK 8u202 version to install the ODI

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while installing odi 12.2.1.4 with jdk-18.0.2.1 as well as jdk-21.0.1.

Then this issue got resolved and installation window got launched successfully after installing and using JavaSEDevelopment Kit 8u381.

[jdk8u381 Downlaod Link](https://www.oracle.com/webapps/redirect/signon?nexturl=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u381-b09/8c876547113c4e4aab3c868e9e0ec572/jdk-8u381-windows-x64.exe)

hope it helps :)